# SQL select rows that have (partially) duplicated data

Tags: sql, duplicate-data, oracle8i

I have the following database schema:

```
Product ID | Component | ...
```

Product ID - a foreign key

Component - parts of the Product

For some Arcane reason a number of Records have the same Product ID & Component. Is there a SQL query that would return all the Product ID's & Components, that have multiple identical Components?

E.g. given the following table

```
| Product ID | Component |
--------------------------
| 1          | c1000     |
| 1          | c1100     |
| 2          | c2000     |
| 2          | c2000     |
| 2          | c2200     |
| 3          | c3000     |
```

The SQL query should return:

```
| Product ID | Component |
--------------------------
| 2          | c2000     |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
  ProductId,
  Component
FROM
  Table
GROUP BY
  ProductId,
  Component
HAVING
  COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: Thanks ... I can see where I was going wrong, I only had the ProductId in the Group by clause!

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT ProductId, Component, count(*) Duplicates
 from MyTable  --  or whatever
 group by ProductId, Component
 having count(*) > 1
```

This will also show you how many duplicate entries there are.

Comment: Should the first line be 'SELECT ProductId, Component, count(*) as Duplicates'?

Answer (score 1):

```
select "Product ID", Component
from table
group by "Product ID", Component
having count(*) > 1
```